# Building a custom kernel in Debian

Tags: debian, linux-kernel

I am not a Debian user, but I need a Debian environment to test this kernel patch I've written, needless to say I've spent the last couple days trying to figure out how to build a custom kernel on Debian, and I'm endlessly frustrated...

I installed a custom kernel successfully but needed to change one config option.  After running `make -j5 deb-pkg` I get this error:

```
dpkg-source: warning: executable mode 0755 of 'debian/linux-headers/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0+/scripts/stackdelta' will not be represented in diff
dpkg-source: warning: executable mode 0755 of 'debian/linux-headers/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0+/scripts/stackusage' will not be represented in diff
dpkg-source: warning: executable mode 0755 of 'debian/linux-headers/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0+/scripts/tags.sh' will not be represented in diff
dpkg-source: warning: executable mode 0755 of 'debian/linux-headers/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0+/scripts/tools-support-relr.sh' will not be represented in diff
dpkg-source: warning: executable mode 0755 of 'debian/linux-headers/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0+/scripts/tracing/draw_functrace.py' will not be represented in diff
dpkg-source: warning: executable mode 0755 of 'debian/linux-headers/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0+/scripts/tracing/ftrace-bisect.sh' will not be represented in diff
dpkg-source: warning: executable mode 0755 of 'debian/linux-headers/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0+/scripts/ver_linux' will not be represented in diff
dpkg-source: warning: executable mode 0755 of 'debian/linux-headers/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0+/scripts/xz_wrap.sh' will not be represented in diff
dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to debian/linux-headers/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0+/tools/objtool/objtool: binary file contents changed
dpkg-source: warning: executable mode 0755 of 'debian/linux-headers/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0+/tools/objtool/objtool' will not be represented in diff
dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to debian/linux-image-dbg/usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/5.8.0+/vmlinux: binary file contents changed
dpkg-source: warning: executable mode 0755 of 'debian/linux-image-dbg/usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/5.8.0+/vmlinux' will not be represented in diff
dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to debian/linux-image-dbg/usr/share/doc/linux-image-5.8.0+-dbg/changelog.Debian.gz: binary file contents changed
dpkg-source: warning: executable mode 0755 of 'debian/linux-image/DEBIAN/postinst' will not be represented in diff
dpkg-source: warning: executable mode 0755 of 'debian/linux-image/DEBIAN/postrm' will not be represented in diff
dpkg-source: warning: executable mode 0755 of 'debian/linux-image/DEBIAN/preinst' will not be represented in diff
dpkg-source: warning: executable mode 0755 of 'debian/linux-image/DEBIAN/prerm' will not be represented in diff
dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to debian/linux-image/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0+: binary file contents changed
dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to debian/linux-image/lib/modules/5.8.0+/modules.alias.bin: binary file contents changed
dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to debian/linux-image/lib/modules/5.8.0+/modules.builtin.bin: binary file contents changed
dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to debian/linux-image/lib/modules/5.8.0+/modules.builtin.modinfo: binary file contents changed
dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to debian/linux-image/lib/modules/5.8.0+/modules.dep.bin: binary file contents changed
dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to debian/linux-image/lib/modules/5.8.0+/modules.symbols.bin: binary file contents changed
dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to debian/linux-image/usr/share/doc/linux-image-5.8.0+/changelog.Debian.gz: binary file contents changed
dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to debian/linux-libc-dev/usr/share/doc/linux-libc-dev/changelog.Debian.gz: binary file contents changed
dpkg-source: warning: the diff modifies the following upstream files: 
 .clang-format
 .cocciconfig
 .config.old
 .get_maintainer.ignore
 .mailmap
 .version
 CREDITS
 MAINTAINERS
 Module.symvers
 README
 u_f.patch
dpkg-source: info: use the '3.0 (quilt)' format to have separate and documented changes to upstream files, see dpkg-source(1)
dpkg-source: error: unrepresentable changes to source
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -i.git -b . subprocess returned exit status 1
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.package:77: deb-pkg] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:1520: deb-pkg] Error 2
```

How can I fix this...?

Answer (score 4):

True, the **dpkg-source** doesn’t ignore some of the earlier built files and you would see errors like these.

```
make -j `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-custom
```

That allows me to build exactly once, after a clean clone. The subsequent build always failed due to problems with **debpkg**

Hence a **make bindeb-pkg** would help for the next build
The command is:

```
make -j `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` bindeb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-custom
```

That works fine and the build succeeds now

Answer (score 2):

While researching this answer, I answered this for non-native packages, but found that the `linux-signed-amd64` source package (which is probably what you are building) is a native package.  Unfortunately that nullifies a lot of what I said in the *Non-Native packages* section, but I think that's still useful for anyone who comes across this question.

## Non-Native packages

Usually when we have this problem it's because we have made untracked changes to a non-native package.  This applies when `debian/source/format` is `3.0 (quilt)`. For example:

```
apt source <package>
cd <package>_<version>
# make changes to sources
dpkg-buildpackage
```

`apt source` downloads the pristine upstream tarball (original author's release unless `+dfsg` is in the version), unpacks it, then adds debian packaging content (found in the `debian/` directory).

When we use `dpkg-buildpackage` (or `debuild`) one of the first things done is that `dpkg-source` is called to verify that anything outside of the `debian/` package is exactly per the pristine upstream tarball.  This ensures that no one at debian adds any undocumented changes.

Any changes to the upstream content needs to be applied independently as a patch.  `quilt` is used for that. The patch is stored in `debian/patches` and gets applied by `dpkg-source` after the verification happens.  This ensures that any distro-specific content is properly documented.  It also helps to track which patches have been forwarded upstream (to the original devs) as there is room for meta-content (or headers) in the patch format.

---

Another way this problem can occur is if the build happens in-source (meaning build artifacts are not isolated to the build directory or scripts will modify source files in-place).  Hopefully `debuild -T clean` will restore everything it its original state, otherwise it needs to be done manually.

---

## Native packages

In this case, `apt source` downloaded the native `linux-signed-amd64_*.tar.xz` source package and then unpacks it.  When we use `debuild` or `dpkg-buildpackage`, we normally generate the source package and all binary packages.  Because the source package already existed, `debuild` skipped this step, but verified that the source package matched the current source tree.  That's where everything failed.  Instead of choosing to replace the source package you had, it chose to throw an error.  Removing the source package (with `debuild -T clean`) solves this conflict.

Comment: I'm building from the git sources (git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git), does this still apply?  the ``deb-pkg`` parameter is defined in the Makefile

Comment: Ah, that explains why linux is a native package.  I bet the `deb-pkg` target calls dpkg-buildpackage in the backend.  I suspect it does still apply. I also suspect that `make clean` probably also does what `debuild -T clean` does when a package is debianized.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the errors were caused by the .deb files and directories that `make deb-pkg` installed to /usr/src, I fixed it by removing them and it looks like it's compiling just fine now

Comment: I'm not sure that your patch is actually applied.  I'll write an answer which explains.